# JQuery clone HTML Selects and insert to a new line inside Row and Col div

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, html-select

I have several HTML Select that I want to clone and insert into a new line inside a new Bootstrap **row** and **col** divs. The snippet is as under:

```js
 $("#subBtn").click(function(){
   var ifType = $("#pcker").clone();
    var ifType2 = $("#pcker2").clone();
   $("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'><div class='col'>");
    $("#scontainer").append(ifType);
    $("#scontainer").append("</div>");
    $("#scontainer").append("<div class='col'>");
    $("#scontainer").append(ifType2);
    $("#scontainer").append("</div></div>");

})
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker">
        <option value='gag'>raps</option>
        <option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
        <option value='gag'>value</option>
        <option value='gag'>select</option>
        <option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>      
      </select>

    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="pcker2">
      <option value='gag2'>raps</option>
      <option value='gag2'>Experiments</option>
      <option value='gag2'>value</option>
      <option value='gag2'>select</option>
      <option value='gag2'>bootstrap</option>
    </select>

    <button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row" id="scontainer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem is that instead of getting the new Selects inside the row and col divs, they are rendered outside the divs.

[image]

How do I insert the new Selects so that the HTML looks like

```
<div class="row"><div> class="col"><select><option></option></select></div><div class="col"><select><option></option></select></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `div` as a whole element (open and close tags) and not in parts. after appending divs, you need to append select boxes inside required div

NOTE: I have added logic to get unique ids of the cloned elements

see below

```
var id1=0;
var id2=0;
$("#subBtn").click(function(){
    var ifType = $("#pcker").clone();
    var ifType2 = $("#pcker2").clone();
    var $row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
    $("#scontainer").append($row);
    var $col1 = $("<div class='col'></div>");
    var $col2 = $("<div class='col'></div>");
    $row.append($col1);
    $row.append($col2);

    $col1.append(ifType);
    $col2.append(ifType2);

   // change id of cloned element just to have unique ids
   $col1.attr('pcker'+id1);
   $col2.attr('pcker1'+id2);
   id1++;
   id2++;
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. The row variables as you suggested did not seem to hold their value across multiple click instances. If I need one row of selects to have the same index, I need to use var index = $("#scontainer .row").length + 1 which seems to work fine.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Try this way:

```js
$("#subBtn").click(function(){
        var ifType = $(".pcker").eq(0).clone(true);
        var ifType2 = $(".pcker2").eq(0).clone(true);
     
      $("#scontainer").append("<div class='row'><div class='col'>");
      $("#scontainer").find('.col').last().append(ifType);
      $("#scontainer").find('.col').last().append(ifType2); 
      $("#scontainer").find('select').last().append("</div></div>"); 
    })
```

```html
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">    
          <div class="col">
            
              <select class="selectpicker pcker" data-live-search="true">
                <option value='gag'>raps</option>
                <option value='gag'>Experiments</option>
                <option value='gag'>value</option>
                <option value='gag'>select</option>
                <option value='gag'>bootstrap</option>      
              </select>

            <select class="selectpicker pcker2" data-live-search="true">
              <option value='gag2'>raps</option>
              <option value='gag2'>Experiments</option>
              <option value='gag2'>value</option>
              <option value='gag2'>select</option>
              <option value='gag2'>bootstrap</option>
            </select>

            <button class="btn" type="button" id="subBtn" value="test">Add Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div id="scontainer"></div>
    </body>
```

Take a look, that I've replaced `id` attribute on `class`, cause, as I said you before, `id` must be unique.

Comment: Your clone select boxes are showing outside the `col` div after inspecting, this is not expected to the OP